# Wrap Text Around Rotated Div

Tags: html, css

I have a heading at an angle with a CSS transform rotation. I want the body text to flow around the rotated text.

If I use `float: left` for the heading, the text appears to wrap around the heading first, and then the heading is actually rotated, causing text to overlap.

An example of my current system is:

```html
<html>
    <h1 style="transform: rotate(-60deg); float:left">
        Test Heading
    </h1>
    <p>
        HLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris diam metus, mollis eu purus vitae, semper fermentum nunc. Phasellus nec iaculis sem, in imperdiet eros. Maecenas ligula nibh, elementum in felis eget, vehicula faucibus nibh. Morbi rhoncus vehicula feugiat. Pellentesque vitae lobortis arcu. Nullam vel mi elementum mi feugiat vehicula. Cras tincidunt purus dolor, eleifend aliquet velit ornare tristique. Maecenas lobortis tristique est, sed facilisis lectus pulvinar vestibulum. Nunc tristique tellus non facilisis elementum. Nam lobortis in velit non tempus. Phasellus lobortis vel neque non iaculis. Praesent tristique risus a gravida imperdiet. Quisque fringilla, massa quis placerat congue, nulla velit varius nisi, vel fermentum tortor velit ut nibh.
    </p>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the goal behavior:
[image]

Comment: Sorry I edited in the code-snippets, but I can't see the problem you are describing? (overlapping text)

Comment: Okay, I edited (with longer body text) to demonstrate the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding margin to the `<h1>`

For example:

```
<html>
<h1 style="transform: rotate(-60deg); float:left; margin:3em 2em;">
    Test Heading
</h1>
<p>
    HLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris diam metus, mollis eu purus vitae, semper fermentum nunc. Phasellus nec iaculis sem, in imperdiet eros. Maecenas ligula nibh, elementum in felis eget, vehicula faucibus nibh. Morbi rhoncus vehicula feugiat. Pellentesque vitae lobortis arcu. Nullam vel mi elementum mi feugiat vehicula. Cras tincidunt purus dolor, eleifend aliquet velit ornare tristique. Maecenas lobortis tristique est, sed facilisis lectus pulvinar vestibulum. Nunc tristique tellus non facilisis elementum. Nam lobortis in velit non tempus. Phasellus lobortis vel neque non iaculis. Praesent tristique risus a gravida imperdiet. Quisque fringilla, massa quis placerat congue, nulla velit varius nisi, vel fermentum tortor velit ut nibh.Nam lobortis in velit non tempus. Phasellus lobortis vel neque non iaculis. Praesent tristique risus a gravida imperdiet. Quisque fringilla, massa quis placerat congue, nulla velit varius nisi, vel fermentum tortor velit ut nibh.Nam lobortis in velit non tempus. Phasellus lobortis vel neque non iaculis. Praesent tristique risus a gravida imperdiet. Quisque fringilla, massa quis placerat congue, nulla velit varius nisi, vel fermentum tortor velit ut nibh.Nam lobortis in velit non tempus. Phasellus lobortis vel neque non iaculis. Praesent tristique risus a gravida imperdiet. Quisque fringilla, massa quis placerat congue, nulla velit varius nisi, vel fermentum tortor velit ut nibh.Nam lobortis in velit non tempus. Phasellus lobortis vel neque non iaculis. Praesent tristique risus a gravida imperdiet. Quisque fringilla, massa quis placerat congue, nulla velit varius nisi, vel fermentum tortor velit ut nibh.
</p>
```

Comment: Well this does avoid overlapping text, but it still rotates after flowing the body text. I'm looking for each line of the body text to start further to the left than the previous line... at the same angle of the rotated heading.

Comment: You mean something like this? https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/

Comment: Yes! Is there a way to do it more easily than CSS Shapes?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the only way I know. But I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix height by adding :before element,

more examples in this article - http://www.benknowscode.com/2014/01/css-rotated-text-parent-dimensions-and-spacing-issues.html

Please check this snippet -

```
    <html>
  <h1>
    Test Heading
  </h1>
  <p>
        HLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris diam metus, mollis eu purus vitae, semper fermentum nunc. Phasellus nec iaculis sem, in imperdiet eros. Maecenas ligula nibh, elementum in felis eget, vehicula faucibus nibh. Morbi rhoncus vehicula feugiat. Pellentesque vitae lobortis arcu. Nullam vel mi elementum mi feugiat vehicula. Cras tincidunt purus dolor, eleifend aliquet velit ornare tristique. Maecenas lobortis tristique est, sed facilisis lectus pulvinar vestibulum. Nunc tristique tellus non facilisis elementum. Nam lobortis in velit non tempus. Phasellus lobortis vel neque non iaculis. Praesent tristique risus a gravida imperdiet. Quisque fringilla, massa quis placerat congue, nulla velit varius nisi, vel fermentum tortor velit ut nibh.
          HLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris diam metus, mollis eu purus vitae, semper fermentum nunc. Phasellus nec iaculis sem, in imperdiet eros. Maecenas ligula nibh, elementum in felis eget, vehicula faucibus nibh. Morbi rhoncus vehicula feugiat. Pellentesque vitae lobortis arcu. Nullam vel mi elementum mi feugiat vehicula. Cras tincidunt purus dolor, eleifend aliquet velit ornare tristique. Maecenas lobortis tristique est, sed facilisis lectus pulvinar vestibulum. Nunc tristique tellus non facilisis elementum. Nam lobortis in velit non tempus. Phasellus lobortis vel neque non iaculis. Praesent tristique risus a gravida imperdiet. Quisque fringilla, massa quis placerat congue, nulla velit varius nisi, vel fermentum tortor velit ut nibh.
  </p>
</html>

h1 {
   display: inline-block;
   white-space: nowrap;
   transform: translate(0,90%) rotate(-60deg);
   transform-origin: 0 0;
   float: left;
}
h1:before {
   content: "";
   float: left;
   margin-top: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nudv9z43

Comment: That doesn't fix the text flow of the paragraph (see comments on other answer for further clarification)

Comment: please add more text and check

Comment: Your example has enough text, that's not the issue. I have provided a screenshot now to make the goal behavior more clear.

Comment: Please check my other snippet,  hope you it will be working for you

Answer (score 0):

Added some "hack" with triangles, hope it will help you -

```
<html>
  <div class="wrap">
  <h1>
    Test Heading Y
  </h1>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
  <div class="four"></div>
  <div class="five"></div>
  <p>
        HLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris diam metus, mollis eu purus vitae, semper fermentum nunc. Phasellus nec iaculis sem, in imperdiet eros. Maecenas ligula nibh, elementum in felis eget, vehicula faucibus nibh. Morbi rhoncus vehicula feugiat. Pellentesque vitae lobortis arcu. Nullam vel mi elementum mi feugiat vehicula. Cras tincidunt purus dolor, eleifend aliquet velit ornare tristique. Maecenas lobortis tristique est, sed facilisis lectus pulvinar vestibulum. Nunc tristique tellus non facilisis elementum. Nam lobortis in velit non tempus. Phasellus lobortis vel neque non iaculis. Praesent tristique risus a gravida imperdiet. Quisque fringilla, massa quis placerat congue, nulla velit varius nisi, vel fermentum tortor velit ut nibh.
         HLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris diam metus, mollis eu purus vitae, semper fermentum nunc. Phasellus nec iaculis sem, in imperdiet eros. Maecenas ligula nibh, elementum in felis eget, vehicula faucibus nibh. Morbi rhoncus vehicula feugiat. Pellentesque vitae lobortis arcu. Nullam vel mi elementum mi feugiat vehicula. Cras tincidunt purus dolor, eleifend aliquet velit ornare tristique. Maecenas lobortis tristique est, sed facilisis lectus pulvinar vestibulum. Nunc tristique tellus non facilisis elementum. Nam lobortis in velit non tempus. Phasellus lobortis vel neque non iaculis. Praesent tristique risus a gravida imperdiet. Quisque fringilla, massa quis placerat congue, nulla velit varius nisi, vel fermentum tortor velit ut nibh.
          HLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris diam metus, mollis eu purus vitae, semper fermentum nunc. Phasellus nec iaculis sem, in imperdiet eros. Maecenas ligula nibh, elementum in felis eget, vehicula faucibus nibh. Morbi rhoncus vehicula feugiat. Pellentesque vitae lobortis arcu. Nullam vel mi elementum mi feugiat vehicula. Cras tincidunt purus dolor, eleifend aliquet velit ornare tristique. Maecenas lobortis tristique est, sed facilisis lectus pulvinar vestibulum. Nunc tristique tellus non facilisis elementum. Nam lobortis in velit non tempus. Phasellus lobortis vel neque non iaculis. Praesent tristique risus a gravida imperdiet. Quisque fringilla, massa quis placerat congue, nulla velit varius nisi, vel fermentum tortor velit ut nibh.
  </p>
  </div>
</html>

h1 {
   display: inline-block;
   white-space: nowrap;
   transform: translate(0,90%) rotate(-25deg);
   transform-origin: 0 0;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 22px;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.wrap > div {
  height: 22px;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  clear: both;
}
.wrap .two {
  width: 200px;
}
.wrap .three {
  width: 150px;
}
.wrap .four {
  width: 100px;
}
.wrap .five {
  width: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nudv9z43/20/